# MySQL closest equivalent of SyBase Update Set From syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sybase

Considering this SyBase code:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET first_name = other.first_name,
    last_name = other.last_name
FROM OTHER_TABLE other
WHERE my_table.id = other.id
```

I want to do exactly the same with MySQL, but it seems I can't put "FROM" right after "SET". What would be the closest equivalent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the tables.

```
UPDATE my_table
JOIN OTHER_TABLE other
ON my_table.id = other.id
SET first_name = other.first_name,
    last_name = other.last_name
```